# Editing Images in Craft Cause Server to Hang

Tags: craft3, plugin-imageoptimize

In the assets area when wanting to edit an image (focus point etc), the server hangs after double clicking an asset.

If you checkmark an asset and then select Edit Image, set the focal point and click save, the website hangs as well.

We are using Forge and hosting images on Digital Ocean Spaces. We are also using the imageOptimize plugin.

This is happening locally as well as on our staging server. Restarting the server is the only way to access craft again.

Where would we start looking to resolve this problem?

The below image illustrates how our image volumes are set up. The settings are defined in the .env.php file and given aliases in the general.php config file.

[image: image volume]

Comment: How are your asset volumes set up?

Comment: Hi Andrew I have updated the original answer showing how volumes are set up.

Comment: @dan-lee Did you ever find a solution here? Having a similar issue.

Comment: I don't remember the resolution, but I do remember it being resolved. It's likely that the php-fpm pool needed to be updated, as the defaults the Forge ships with are woefully low.